# Delete Cascade doesn`t work, already tried every solution I found

Tags: java, spring, rest, cascade

Spring   Rest API application. So, when I delete one User(I want to delete also the orders for that user). The user id is foreign key for the order(one to many relation).

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "order_products", 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
private List<OrderHasProduct> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

The user class

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "orders", 
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<OrderHasProduct> orders = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean deleteUser(int id){
    User usr = usrRepository.findById(id);
    if (usr == null) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(User.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    usrRepository.delete(id);
    User deletedUser = usrRepository.findById(id);
    if (deletedUser != null) 
       return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: And then what`s the use of Cascade?

Comment: Is that a typo, or do you have the `orders` list in both the `User` class and the `OrderHasProduct` class? Can you show the class declarations on the two code snippets to make it clearer which class is which? At least one thing that jumps out (aside from the orders list being in both classes) is that your `mappedBy` is pointing to the wrong field.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the `OrderHasProduct` class as well?
Here’s an working example:

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post", 
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructors, getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class PostComment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String review;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;

    //Constructors, getters and setters

    }
}
```

Comment: The other side doesn't actually need `@ManyToOne`; it would just be a [unidirectional](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-filter-join-table) mapping.

Comment: @dyslexit You are totally right, I edited my answer, thanks!